# javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function call ResizeableTextbox('myRT'); works well inside javascript(produces a resizeable text box) but doesn't work inside jQuery code.Why?

This produces the resizeable textbox.

`<script type="text/javascript">`
  ResizeableTextbox('myRT');
`</script>`

But if I give it like this in the jquery code,I dont get the resizeable textbox.

```
$(".select").change(function () {          
       $(".select"+increment+" option:selected").each(function ()    
       {              
         if($(this).text() =='String')
         {
           $("<label id=labelid >"+label+"</label>").appendTo(".menu li");    
           ResizeableTextbox('myRT');//this does not work.How else to code?
         }
       });
 });
```

Is there any method for function call in jQuery?

Update:

The function call ResizeableTextbox('myRT'); doesn't work anywhere within the jQuery code. It works only inside `<script>`.

How else to write this function call? some one help me please..

Answer (score 2):

You want to append the resizable textbox to .menu li?
You could do this:

```
var rt = new ResizeableTextbox('myRT'); //this is for making resizeable text box
$('.menu li').append(rt);
```

However Im not quite sure if this is what you wan't. Your question is rather vague.

Comment: ya.. you are correct.. I want to append the resizeable text box to .menu li. 

Previously I just had a text box,
$("<input id=inputstr type= 'text' ></input>").appendTo(".menu li");

Now instead of this I need the resizeable text box.
If I code what you had said,it throws error.. the page goes blank..

Answer (score 2):

It depends greatly on exactly what 'rt' will contain and how it is then added to the DOM.

If it just contains HTML then obviously `$(parentSelector).html(rt)` would solve the problem.
If it returns a DOM element then `$(rt).appendTo(parentSelector);`
If it something else, or is added to the DOM inside your `ResizeableTextbox` code then I couldn't possibly guess.

Update: If you are using the resizable textbox detailed here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-controls-resizeable-textbox then you would use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rt = new ResizeableTextbox();
  $('#resizable').append(rt.GetContainer());
  rt.StartListening();
});
```

Comment: rt is a text box that can be resized.

Comment: Yes, but is it a string of HTML, or a DOM element or something else?

Comment: @ samjudson

I also tried what you have given:


var rt=new ResizeableTextbox('myRT'); $(parentSelector).append($(rt.GetContainer()));

no result. The page goes blank( says page loading)

Comment: The function call ResizeableTextbox('myRT'); doesn't work anywhere within the jQuery code. It works only inside `<script>`.

How else to write this function call?

Comment: Err, not sure what you mean. Your jquery code should be in a script.

Comment: Its actually not jquery code,it's a java script code..
So it works only within <script></script>.

I'm not able to use it inside the $(document).ready() function. The page goes blank(says page is loading).

Please help me out with this.

Comment: jquery IS javascript. Both should be within a <script></script> element. I can't see you code so I don't have any idea why it still says 'page loading'. The code I gave above works fine for me.